# many to many issues with eloquent while using pivot table

Tags: php, database, laravel, database-design, laravel-5

I have 3 tables. user, theme and theme_user. Its because I need a many to many relationship. I created in both the models the following:

// Theme.php

```
public function users() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'theme_user', 'theme_code', 'user_id'); }
```

//User.php

```
public function themes() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\Theme', 'theme_user', 'user_id', 'theme_code'); }
```

Now I want to get all users from a certain theme. Therefor I do

```
$themeUser = Theme::where('code', '=', $code)->first()->users;
```

But the query I get is not right..

```
'select users.*, theme_user.theme_code as pivot_theme_code, theme_user.user_id as pivot_user_id from users inner join theme_user on users.id = theme_user.user_id where theme_user.theme_code is null'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What's wrong with the query?

Comment: Well.. I need to get the users who are assigned to a theme. With this query I don't get that result.

Comment: Everything looks correct. The only thing that I can think of that would cause this is if the `theme_code` for the `Theme` record that is found is null. What do you get from a `dd(Theme::where('code', '=', $code)->first());`?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation on hasManyThrough():  http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#has-many-through

In your case, it would be something like:

```
class User
{
    public function themes()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('ThemeUser', 'Theme');
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no requirement of hasManyThrough this is just a case of pivot table

Comment: But then I have to create a ThemeUser model? thats a model from two models.. Don't think thats really a best practice is it?